# how to find ratings only to movie nodes in neo4j using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
CREATE (movie:Movie { title : 'The Matrix', year : '1999-03-31' })
CREATE (hotel:Hotel { name : 'Noushad Fried Chicken', acronym : 'NBC' })
CREATE (me:User { name: "Me" })
CREATE (me)-[:RATED { stars : 5, comment : "I love that movie!" }]->(movie);
CREATE (me)-[:RATED { stars : 3.5, comment : "food is great" }]->(hotel);
```

I want to find all the movies rated by me, but i when i try the following query

```
MATCH (me:User { name: "Me" }),(me)-[rating:RATED]->(movie) 
RETURN movie.title, rating.stars, rating.comment;
```

I get results including hotel ratings.

```
movie.title     rating.stars    rating.comment
The Matrix          5           I love that movie!
                    3.5         food is great
```

What is the query to get only the movie rating by me?

Comment: Perhaps it also makes sense to have different `RATED` relationship-types for hotels and movies? E.g. `RATED_MOVIE` and `RATED_HOTEL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restrict the ratings to movies you should specify the corresponding node label in the pattern:

```
MATCH (me:User { name: "Me" })-[rating:RATED]->(movie:Movie) 
RETURN movie.title, rating.stars, rating.comment;
```